# c++ mysql prepared statements close and unique_ptr

Tags: c++, mysql, pointers, unique-ptr

I have 2 questions related to c++ and mysql connector.

1. If I use sql::PreparedStatement as unique_ptr, do I need to call the close() method of prepareStatement or is it called automatically when unique_ptr is deleted? Do I also need to close the sql::resultSet?
2. Do you need to call the reset () method of unique_ptr to remove that pointer?

I have this function that receives a unique_ptr from PreparedStatement, executes the query and returns the result.

```
    std::unique_ptr<sql::ResultSet> CommonService::select(std::unique_ptr<sql::PreparedStatement> &pstmt) {
std::unique_ptr<sql::ResultSet> resulSet = nullptr;
    try {
        resulSet = std::unique_ptr<sql::ResultSet>(pstmt->executeQuery());
        pstmt->close(); // i need to do this? or is closed when unique_ptr is deleted?
       // pstmt.reset(); i need to do this? or is deleted automatically
    } catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
        std::cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
        std::cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << std::endl;
        std::cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
        std::cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
        std::cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << std::endl;
        pstmt->close(); // i need to do this? or is closed when unique_ptr is deleted?
    }

    return resulSet;
}
```

thanks

Comment: *do I need to call the close() method of prepareStatement or is it called automatically when unique_ptr is deleted?* -- What does the destructor of `sql::ResultSet` do?  A `unique_ptr` has no knowledge of what the type does -- it relies on the type's destructor to do the work of cleaning up the resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I use sql::PreparedStatement as unique_ptr, do I need to call the
>   close() method of prepareStatement or is it called automatically when
>   unique_ptr is deleted? Do I also need to close the sql::resultSet?

No, you don't need to call the close() method. Initialize your query statement only once like so. The query statement will be automatically destroyed once it goes out of scope. Handle your database exceptions without closing the statement.

As far as your resultSet is concerned, you can declare it as a local variable like so

```
// global scope
std::unique_ptr<sql::Connection> sqlConnection;
std::unique_ptr<sql::Statement> stmt;

void InitializeDatabase() { // call once
   sqlConnection.reset(sqlDriver->connect(host, user, pwd));
   stmt.reset(sqlConnection->createStatement());
}

void getData(/* */)
{    
    std::unique_ptr<sql::ResultSet> res(stmt->executeQuery(/**/));    
    do {
        while (res->next()) {  // extract data from statement
            /* */
        }
    } while (stmt->getMoreResults());  
} // res will be automatically destroyed here.
```

> Do you need to call the reset () method of unique_ptr to remove that
>   pointer?

No, unique_ptr objects will be destroyed automatically once they go out of scope.